# How to set map key in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am using reactjs by applying typescript. I am using  in the map, but if I give a unique numer value to the key, an error occurs.
Anyone know why?

```js
atom.js

export interface Person {
  id: Number;
  num: string;
  name: string;
  img: string;
}
....

export const filteredPersonList = selector({
  key: "filteredPersonListSelector",
  get: ({ get }) => {
    const filterType = get(filteredType);
    const filterSearch = get(filteredSearch);
    const person = get(person);

    if (filterSearch.length > 0 && filterType !== "all") {
      const filteredList = person
        .filter((p) =>p.name.includes(filterSearch))
        .filter((p) =>p.type.includes(filterType));
      return filteredList;
    } else if (filterSearch.length > 0 && filterType === "all") {

      return filteredList;
    } else if (filterType !== "all") {

      return filteredList;
    } else {
      return person;
    }
  },
});
```

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useRecoilState, useRecoilValue, useSetRecoilState } from "recoil";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {
filteredPersonList
} from "../store/atom";

interface TypeItemComp {
  currentType: boolean;
}

export default function Main() {
  const [filterType, setFilterType] = useRecoilState(filteredType);
  const people = useRecoilValue(filteredPersonList);

  return (
    <MainContainer>
      <PersonContainer>
        {people.map((p) => (
          <Link key={p.id} to={`/detail/${p.id}`}>. //an error occurs here

          </Link>
        ))}
      </PersonContainer>
    </MainContainer>
  );
}
```

The warning is as below.

> Type 'Number' is not assignable to type 'Key | null | undefined'.
> Type 'Number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
> 'number' is a primitive, but 'Number' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'number' when possible.ts(2322)
> index.d.ts(138, 9): The expected type comes from property 'key' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & RefAttributes'

Comment: change `id: Number;` to `id: number;`, as the error states as well

Comment: As it says right in the message: "Prefer using 'number' when possible."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use number instead of Number. "Number" with a capital N isn't the datatype you're looking for. It even says so in the error message.

I know error messages may look overwhelming sometimes, especially when you're just starting out as a programmer. But most of the time, they're awesome.

You should try and make a habit of carefully READING the error messages you get, instead of just being alarmed by it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll take your advice and try to look more closely at the error message in the future. :)